# Wrong filed value in pydantic model

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

This is my pydantic class

```py
class UploadResult(BaseModel):
    reference: str
    tag_uid: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, alias="tagUid")

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

whenever I'm calling it like this I'm getting the value of `tag_uid` to None.

```py
UploadResult(reference='b07b2068fe523c849cddb3dddf9d55fcb109bc5d302ef726738cfc3d83cb6b29', tag_uid=123)
>>> UploadResult(reference='b07b2068fe523c849cddb3dddf9d55fcb109bc5d302ef726738cfc3d83cb6b29'), tag_uid=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `tag_uid` to `tagUid`.

```py
UploadResult(reference='b07b2068fe523c849cddb3dddf9d55fcb109bc5d302ef726738cfc3d83cb6b29', tagUid=123)
```